# Add action save post when create and publish

Tags: hooks, save-post

I try to use the hook save_post in my wp but I have a problem. I do this :

```
function when_save_post_match($post_id, $post){

if (isset($post->post_status) && 'auto-draft' == $post->post_status) {
    return;
}

if( 'match' == $post->post_type ){

    $id_match = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_select_match_from_db', true );

    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO posts_matchs (id_match,id_post) VALUES
        (
            :id_match,
            :id_post
        )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_match = :id_match, id_post = :id_post');
    $req->bindParam(':id_match', $id_match);
    $req->bindParam(':id_post', $post_id);
    $req->execute();
    $req->closeCursor();
}
}
add_action('save_post', 'when_save_post_match', 10, 2);
```

When I create a custom post "match", the action of inserting data into the db is NOT DONE. When I update a custom post "match", the action IS DONE.
When I create and then delete a post match, the action IS DONE.

I would like the action to be taken when I create a custom post match (and update) and just for the published post.

I don't understand how to do this.

Any idea ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

With transition post status :

```
function when_save_post_match( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
if ( ( 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status ) && 'match' === $post->post_type) {

        $id_match = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_select_match_from_db', true );

        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO posts_matchs (id_match,id_post) VALUES
        (
            :id_match,
            :id_post
        )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_match = :id_match, id_post = :id_post');
        $req->bindParam(':id_match', 32);
        $req->bindParam(':id_post', 20);
        $req->execute();
        $req->closeCursor();

}}add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'when_save_post_match', 10, 3 );
```

This code does not work :-( and when I create a new match the mesage "publication failed" appears the first time I click on "publish" and desappear after clicking a second time on the "publish" button... Don't understand what Is going on

Comment: `save_post` is a misleading name - it fires a lot more than you would expect. Look into the post status transitions hooks instead. Either `transition_post_status` where you can specify what old and new status you want to trigger things on - i.e. if `new_status` is `publish` and `old_status` is not `publish`, you know it's a brand-new published post - or else something like `publish_post` which will fire for both brand-new published posts and anytime a published post is updated, only for the `post` post_type. https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Comment: Thanks I try with status but it does not work... I don't understand. Nothing in my table of my database when I publish or update a match cutom post. I edit my first message to display the code I used. Thanks

Comment: After more tests, I think the problem is not this : I want to intercept the data in a custom fields and insert it in a table in my database. When I publish it can't be possible because this field is  not already in the post_meta table in WP. So it works when I update the post but not when I publish the post....

Answer (score 0):

I think one key question here is how `_select_match_from_id` meta value is saved? Is it some metafield on the post edit screen or from some other logic?

If I may assume that it is from a metafield, then you could just read its value from the `$_POST` array.

---

You could also improve your code by splitting the callback function into two, one for new posts and the other for updates, and moving the database action into a separate function.

Using the `save_post_{$post->post_type}` helps you eliminate the post type check from the callback. The `save_post` callback recieves also a third parameter `bool $update` which you can use to determine, if it is a new post that is saved or an post update.

So you could for example do the following,

```
// Use post type specific actions to eliminate post type checking in callback
add_action('save_post_match', 'when_save_post_match', 10, 3);
add_action('save_post_match', 'when_update_post_match', 10, 3);

function when_save_post_match(int $post_id, WP_Post $post, bool $update) {
  // only new posts
  if ( $update ) {
    return;
  }
  // get data for new post
  $id_match = new_posts_match_from_db($post_id);
  // pass id and data to action
  execute_database_action($post_id, $id_match);
}

function new_posts_match_from_db(int $post_id) {
  // this could be from the posted values as below or some other logic
  // TODO: update to match your setup
  return $_POST['_select_match_from_db'] ?? null;
}

function when_update_post_match(int $post_id, WP_Post $post, bool $update) {
  // only updates
  if ( ! $update ) {
    return;
  }
  // get data from post meta
  $id_match = existing_posts_match_from_db($post_id);
  // pass id and data to action
  execute_database_action( $post_id, $id_match );
}

function existing_posts_match_from_db(int $post_id) {
  return get_post_meta( $post_id, '_select_match_from_db', true );
}

function execute_database_action(int $post_id, $id_match) {
  // your db action...
}
```

*Modify as needed.*